# get specific ip adress from a string using php

Tags: php, compare, ip-address

I wrote a script to search an ip address from a string, it works fine in normal cases but creates problem in special case. Here is my code. this script does not work in the following case.

```
<?php
if(preg_match("/\b1.1.1.1\b/", "this is test 109.111.1.1"))
{
echo "A match was found.";
}
else
{
echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape the dots:

```
if(preg_match("/\b1\.1\.1\.1\b/", "this is test 109.111.1.1"))
```

Comment: i have tried this but still no result although the strings are same....please help meif(preg_match("/\b109\.97\.111\.111\b/", "109.111.1.1"))

Comment: i want to search ip in a string that may contain "abccdef lkjklj 109.97.11.11"

Comment: yes but the issue resolved with pattern matching

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex pattern,

```
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

the problem with your current regex is that `.` can match any character. escape it with `\` so it will match on `period`.

Comment: thnx but have a look at this and try this, not working if(preg_match("/\b109\.97\.111\.111\b/", "109.111.1.1")) echo 'matched...';

Comment: what do you want to get? can you explain more?

Comment: if the ip is matched then print a success message otherwise error message

Comment: what did you do that slves your problem?

Comment: \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b